# Is use of function return values for error checking and/or exception handling good and proper technique?

Tags: c, function, error-handling, exception, return-value

I've inherited a C system which makes use of function return values to check for errors and exceptions; something like this:

```
#define OK 1

int create_cheese(const char * myType, float myCost, char * myCheese) {
   // Do Stuff...

   if // everything looks good
       return 1;
   else
       return // error/exception code
}

int main() {
    rc = create_cheese("cheddar", 12.99, &cheese);
    if (rc != OK) { exit(rc); }

    return 1;
}
```

Is this considered proper C technique?

These functions are not very, well, functional. In other words, they don't use the function return values as meaningful data relevant to program execution; they're used for error and exception handling. Thank you, Keith :^)

Answer (score 4):

> Is this considered proper C technique?

I have found no matching *return 1 on success* parallel in the C language or standard library.

C has at least 6 different ways it communicates errors.  Many listed below.

OP's posted technique is a variation returning error/success status.

It suffers from 2 weaknesses

- `OK` is too common an identifier and will likely collided with other code.  Far too easy to find `OK` defined as 0.
- Opposite zero-ness. `OK` as 0 is more common.

OP's error approach is **not proper** as it is yet another *unnecessary* variation on existing techniques.

---

Various C error / exception / *the unhappy path* handling

- Return error/success (not data, but maybe error data)

  - Success is 0, else return a non-zero `errno_t`: *Many* `..._s()` functions. (**Similar to OP's** - yet non-zero success)
  - Success is 0, else non-zero.  `remove(), raise()`
- Return data - a few (maybe only one) values indicate error/special.

  - `NULL` is bad, else a pointer.  `fgets(), setlocale(), bsearch()`
  - `NULL` is maybe bad, else a pointer.  `malloc`
  - 0 is bad, else various others are good.  `fread()`
  - -1 is bad, else various others are good.  `time(), fseek()`
  - `EOF` - a negative. 0 or more is good. `fgetc()`
  - `FP_ILOGB0, FP_ILOGBNAN` else some `int`.  `ilogb()`
  - any negative is bad, else value is informative. `printf()`.
  - Largest few values have special meaning, else some unsigned.  `mbrtoc16()`
- Via state/instance object: Many I/O functions return `EOF` to indicate end of file **or** I/O error.  Other functions used to determine detail. `feof()`, `ferror()`.
- Global

  - Error code `errno`: `strtol()`
  - Floating-point environment: `fegetexceptflag()`
- Not-a-number: NaN sits in limbo between error codes and values.  `log(negative_x), atanh(x_more_than_1)`
- UB: Simply not handling the error in a specified way: e.g. `1/0`

---

One style I do not see with the standard C library, though is other libraries, is `bool foo(..., int *error_code)` - passing is a place to store/update the error detail.

Comment: I'll give you a dollar to enumerate the six ways. Seriously, I want to know.

Comment: @kmiklas Recent post in the last week had some - have not found it, I''ll list some..

Comment: I know you know this, but technically `0.0/0.0` is *undefined* although IEEE754 defines it.

Comment: I'd clump all the *return error status (x is good, y is bad)* into a single category

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way, but you can follow the rules of the existing macro-constant `EXIT_SUCCESS` (= 0) and `EXIT_FAILURE` (= -1). So I suggest to return a value `!= 0` when there is an error .

Answer (score 2):

Since C doesn't support exceptions, the only way to test for an error after a function call is to examine a designated error holding variable.  There are a few ways you can do this:

1. Return the error / success indication from the function (i.e. `errno_t foo(int bar);`)
2. Make the error / success indication an output pointer parameter (i.e. `void foo(int bar, errno_t *error_code);`)
3. Use an operating system error indicator (i.e. `SetLastError` on Windows, or `errno`).

I'm a fan of method #2, since it's a lot harder to ignore that there's an error parameter with:

```
errno_t err;
myfunction(100, &err);
```

Instead of:

```
errno_t err = myfunction(100); // You could just as easily not assign the return value
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly valid way of handling errors, particularly as C doesn't have exceptions like C++ or Java does.

You check the return value to see if the function was successful or not, and use the parameters to get back information from the function.  Plenty of library functions work in this manner, so it's a well known idoim in C.

You can also mix returning meaningful values and error codes.  For example, the `write` library function returns the number of bytes read, or -1 if an error occurred.  In the case of an error, it also sets the global `errno` which contains the actual error code.

Comment: At least in the C11 standard, `errno` should be thread-local.

Answer (score 1):

The convention in C (it's *almost* formalised in the standard) is to return 0 for success. So your returning 1 is idiosyncratic and ought to be changed.

This can be extended to return negative for failures and positive for near-failures.

When returning from `main` you ought to assume that the operating system will only deal with 8 bits of the return value, and possibly unsigned too which, maddeningly, is in contradiction with returning a negative for failure! That's the good thing about standards: there are so many to choose from.

Comment: Here's how close "almost" is:  Per [**7.22.4.4 The exit function**, paragraph 5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.4p5):  "... If the value of status is **zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`**..."  I'd like to find a C implementation that **doesn't** define `EXIT_SUCCESS` as zero.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Yes, it's *really* annoying. Thanks for taking the time to find the point in the standard. I knew it was there somewhere.